# Как составить регулярное выражение для поиска подстроки (первое и последнее вхождение)?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `img/egor/фывыв/`
Пытаюсь найти подстроку img/ регуляркой `(.*\/)`, но находит все вхождения. Как ограничить до первого? И отдельным рег. выражением взять последнее вхождение.

Comment: Получайте всё, а потом из $matches выбирайте нужный элемент.

Comment: `.*` замените на `.*?`

Comment: комбинацию с `explode` и `array_push/pop` тоже никто не отменял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов — ограничивать набор *подходящих* символов, вместо точки писать `[^\/]`, то есть все символы, кроме слеша.

```
^[^\/]*\/?
```

Первая папка в пути со слешем, если он есть. Самый первый символ крышка `^` означает совпадение с началом строки.

```
\/?[^\/]*$
```

Это самый последний сегмент пути со слешем, если есть. Доллар `$` означает совпадение с концом строки.

**UPDATE**

Совсем забыл, что слеши требуют экранирования в регэкспах. Вместо `/` надо писать `\/`. Сейчас работает, см. https://regex101.com/r/njDqHf/1

Comment: У меня не работает не для первого, не для последнего https://regex101.com/r/QFhGcl/2

Comment: Поменяйте ограничители шаблона, например на тильды "~", тогда заработает.

Comment: @Frontender, забыл, что надо экранировать символ слеш. Исправил, сейчас работает, проверил на regex101.com.

Comment: Да не надо его экранировать - в таких случаях выбирают другой символ для ограничителя.

Comment: Насчет последнего вхождения, не работает, т.к. строка была другая.

Comment: Там просто берется слэш

Comment: @Frontender, если слеш именно на конце, то `[^\/]*\/?$`. Последняя часть пути плюс последний слеш, если он есть.